# I need to create a field that is the second date to a maxdate

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Server database includes all contracts. my query finds the contract value for the latest date, I need another column that shows the contract value for the second last contract.

Example:

```
ContractID  ordd_mn_end_date    ord_mn_billed_amt
-------------------------------------------------
8198        10-31-2021           2574.43
8198        10-31-2020           833.15
```

What I would like to happen is for the ExpiringAmt 2 to show 833.15

Code

```
SELECT 
    det.ordd_ContractItemID,
    det.ordd_mn_end_date,
    det.ordd_mn_billed_amt AS Expiring_Amt,
    det.ordd_mn_billed_amt AS Expiring_Amt2
FROM 
    ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_orddet det
WHERE 
    det.ordd_mn_end_date IN (SELECT MAX(det.ordd_mn_end_date) 
                             FROM ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_orddet det 
                             GROUP BY det.ordd_ContractItemID)
    AND det.ordd_ContractItemID IN (8198)
ORDER BY 
    det.ordd_mn_end_date DESC
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Which version of sql server?

Comment: Look at [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); with `order by` `order date desc` and then `select` rows 1 and 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with window functions LAG() and ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT ContractID, ordd_mn_end_date, Expiring_Amt, Expiring_Amt2
FROM (
  SELECT ContractID,
         ordd_mn_end_date,
         ord_mn_billed_amt Expiring_Amt,
         LAG(ord_mn_billed_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY ContractID ORDER BY ordd_mn_end_date) Expiring_Amt2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractID ORDER BY ordd_mn_end_date DESC) rn
  FROM lti_orddet 
  WHERE ContractID IN (8198)
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you are interested only in 1 `ContractID`, like your query, then you can remove `PARTITION BY ContractID` from both window functions.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bbfba2ebf4beb03667d51932e3150031).
Results:

| ContractID | ordd_mn_end_date | Expiring_Amt | Expiring_Amt2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8198 | 2021-10-31 | 2574.43 | 833.15 |

Answer (score 0):

I would use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to append the next or previous value of `ordd_mn_billed_amt` , and then use `ROW_NUMBER()` to always pick the first row...

```
WITH
  lti_orddet_augmented AS
(
  SELECT
    lti_orddet.*,
    LEAD(ord_mn_billed_amt)
      OVER (PARTITION BY ordd_ContractItemID
                ORDER BY ordd_mn_end_date DESC
           )
             AS ord_mn_billed_amt_previous,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY ordd_ContractItemID
                ORDER BY ordd_mn_end_date DESC
           )
             AS ordd_ContractItemID_RowNum
  FROM
    ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_orddet
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  lti_orddet_augmented 
WHERE
      ordd_ContractItemID_RowNum = 1
  AND ordd_ContractItemID        = 8198
```

In this case I used `LEAD()` so that the window for both functions is in the same order.

Comment: I used the first query because this is going to be added to an existing query. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!